# How to find status bar of a browser is appearing or not through jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a small site. For that i designed some layout. Every thing is fine except the height. I am giving the main div height as the height of the document with `$(document).height()`. Because of the status bar, i have to reduce the 2pixels from the resultant height. In IE9 looking good. But when I open same in the Firefox there is some gap at the bottom. Browsers are looking like this.

[image]
[image]

Now I want to adjust the height based on the visibility of the status bar which is presented at the bottom of the IE browser. How to find it is visible or not  through jquery

Comment: Are you sure that your `main` div is right at the top of your page? BTW: A bit code would help us sometimes more ;)

Comment: Yeah... main div is presented after the body tag only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible - but feel free to prove me wrong.  On a side note status bar is not the only thing that can appear at the bottom; I have several addon that add additional status notifications that pop in/out as the page loads, so attempting to determine if the status bar is visible or not may not be the best approach.

Each user will also have different size screen/resolution, so, you can expect different size view windows.

With that in mind have you considered setting the `div` to have the following

```
position:absolute;
top:0; right:0;
bottom:10px; left:0;
```

This will ensure the div is the size of the screen minus a few pixels from the bottom.

Comment: Initially I gave `position:relative`. But After I changed to absolute and change the another parameters also.. it is looking fine. :)